# How to display the last data-index attribute in a specified HTML tag

Tags: javascript

I wonder how I can catch the last data-attribute item and show its value in a certain span tag. I attach a small code of how it should look like:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lkt0jpex/
or here(same code):

```
   <HTML>
     <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title></title>
      <meta name="author" content="">
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>
      <!-- Get last item of data-index attribute -->
      <div class="wq" data-index="18"></div>
      <div class="wq" data-index="19"></div>
      <!-- Display it as a string in span.test -->
      <span class="test">//VALUE OF DATA-INDEX="19"//</span>
      <script src="js/script.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CSS selector `:last-of-type` inside a [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to get the last item with the class `.wq` then read the index via the [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) property.

```js
const lastElement = document.querySelector(".wq:last-of-type");
const testElement = document.querySelector(".test");

testElement.textContent = lastElement.dataset.index;
```

```html
<div class="wq" data-index="18"></div>
<div class="wq" data-index="19"></div>
<!-- Display it as a string in span.test -->
<span class="test">//VALUE OF DATA-INDEX="19"//</span>
```

Another option is to select all items with the `data-index` attribute and get the value of the last item found.

```js
const lastElement = document.querySelector("[data-index]:last-of-type");
const testElement = document.querySelector(".test");

testElement.textContent = lastElement.dataset.index;
```

```html
<div class="wq" data-index="18"></div>
<div class="wq" data-index="19"></div>
<!-- Display it as a string in span.test -->
<span class="test">//VALUE OF DATA-INDEX="19"//</span>
```